# sort pandas value_counts() primarily by descending counts and secondarily by ascending values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

When applying value_counts() to a series in pandas, by default the counts are sorted in descending order, however the values are not sorted within each count.

How can i have the values within each identical count sorted in ascending order?

```
apples    5
peaches   5
bananas   3
carrots   3
apricots  1
```

Comment: Can you please  show example of DataFrame or Series with the expected output?

Comment: Are you talking about the index values? unfortunately the default sort will always sort this in descending order I've found

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The output of value_counts is a series itself (just like the input), so you have available all of the standard sorting options as with any series.  For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'fruit':['apples']*5  + ['peaches']*5 + ['bananas']*3 +
                            ['carrots']*3 + ['apricots'] })

df.fruit.value_counts().reset_index().sort([0,'index'],ascending=[False,True])

      index  0
0    apples  5
1   peaches  5
2   bananas  3
3   carrots  3
4  apricots  1
```

I'm actually getting the same results by default so here's a test with `ascending=[False,False]` to demonstrate that this is actually working as suggested.

```
df.fruit.value_counts().reset_index().sort([0,'index'],ascending=[False,False])

      index  0
1   peaches  5
0    apples  5
3   carrots  3
2   bananas  3
4  apricots  1
```

I'm actually a bit confused about exactly what desired output here in terms of ascending vs descending, but regardless, there are 4 possible combos here and you can get it however you like by altering the `ascending` keyword argument.

Comment: thanks! what i was missing is the reset_index() part. can you explain its function here?

Comment: also will need to add e.g. in to_csv: , header=False , index=False

Comment: @eyaler  `reset_index` converts the existing index to a column, which makes the sort easier.  `sort` can operate on either the index or columns but not both at the same time (as far as I know)