# pandas value_counts: sort by value, then alphabetically?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'fruit':
       ['peaches']*5 + ['apples']*5 + ['bananas']*3 + 
       ['nectarines']*3 + ['carrots']*3 + ['apricots'] 
})
```

And I would like to get output sorted first by the value count, then alphabetically by the name of the fruit:

```
apples        5
peaches       5
bananas       3
carrots       3
nectarines    3
apricots      1
```

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31431553/sort-pandas-value-counts-primarily-by-descending-counts-and-secondarily-by-asc), but it looks out of date.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Seems like just using `value_counts` will yield the result

```
df.fruit.value_counts()
Out[818]: 
apples        5
peaches       5
bananas       3
carrots       3
nectarines    3
apricots      1
Name: fruit, dtype: int64
```

Update

```
df.fruit.value_counts().sort_index(ascending=False).sort_values(ascending=False)    

apples        5
peaches       5
bananas       3
carrots       3
nectarines    3
apricots      1
Name: fruit, dtype: int64
```

Comment: which pandas and python? I get peaches before apples.

Comment: @ALollz pd.__version__
Out[821]: '0.23.4'

Comment: @ALollz can you try the update work for you or not ?

Comment: Thanks! So for reference, the complete solution is `df.fruit.value_counts().sort_index(ascending=False).sort_values(ascending=False)`

Comment: It seems like it depends on the version! With `1.3.1` it only works as `df.fruit.value_counts().sort_index(ascending=True).sort_values(ascending=False)` (as it should be, since `'a' < 'p'`, it is ascending!), but with `1.1.2` it's vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this but the output will be a list of tuples that is sorted alphabetically by fruit name with the number of fruits. First turn the value_counts() output into a dictionary then use the items function to turn that into a list of tuples and sort those:

`sorted(dict(df.fruit.value_counts()).items())`

Answer (score 0):

**Note: there is some confusion around the accepted answer. I recommend to use this solution to make sure it runs deterministically across different versions.**

You can do this (if you don't really care about the details):

```py
df.fruit.value_counts().reset_index().sort_values(
    ['fruit', 'index'], ascending=[False, True]
)
```

Output as a dataframe:

```
        index  fruit
1      apples      5
0     peaches      5
2     bananas      3
4     carrots      3
3  nectarines      3
5    apricots      1
```

But if you do care, that is the precise answer:

```py
df.fruit.value_counts().reset_index().sort_values(
    ['fruit', 'index'], ascending=[False, True]
).set_index('index').rename_axis(None)['fruit']
```

Output in the exactly the same format:

```
apples        5
peaches       5
bananas       3
carrots       3
nectarines    3
apricots      1
Name: fruit, dtype: int64
```